# Ajax WebGrid JQuery issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the webgrid so i can display data from my database. On page load the grid is displaying correctly on the page, but when i try to filter the data, i have a textbox and a submit button, when i press on the search button i get an error : "a jquery script reference is required in order to enable ajax support in the webgrid helper". I cant seem to find were the problem is.

this is my grid in my view,
Hello,
I am using the webgrid so i can display data from my database. On page load the grid is displaying correctly on the page, but when i try to filter the data, i have a textbox and a submit button, when i press on the search button i get an error : "a jquery script reference is required in order to enable ajax support in the webgrid helper". I cant seem to find were the problem is.

this is my grid in my view,

```
        <div id="myGrid">
            @Html.Partial("Grids/_gridPayments", Model)
        </div>
```

this is my partial webgrid view

```
@model IEnumerable<DAS.DAL.CustomerPayment>

@{  
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 15, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "myGrid");

@grid.GetHtml(rowStyle: "gridRow", alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow", footerStyle: "gridFooter", columns: grid.Columns(
                   grid.Column("FullName", "Πελάτης"),
                   grid.Column("Amount", "Ποσό", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:C}", item.Amount)),
                   grid.Column("Descr", "Περιγραφή"),
                   grid.Column("DTPaid", "Ημερομηνία πληρωμής", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", item.DTPaid))
               ));
}
```

and finally my controller function is 

`var payments = BLPayments.getAllPayments();`

```
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchCustomer))
           payments = payments.Where(a => a.FullName.Contains(txtSearchCustomer)).ToList();
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchFromDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchToDate))
           payments = payments.Where(a => a.DTPaid >= DateTime.ParseExact(txtSearchFromDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", null) && a.DTPaid <= DateTime.ParseExact(txtSearchToDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", null)).ToList();
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchFromDate) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchToDate))
           payments = payments.Where(a => a.DTPaid >= DateTime.ParseExact(txtSearchFromDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", null)).ToList();
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchFromDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchToDate))
           payments = payments.Where(a => a.DTPaid <= DateTime.ParseExact(txtSearchToDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", null)).ToList();

       return PartialView("Grids/_gridPayments", payments);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: the odd thing is that i can sort the webgrid with no problem, the first time the page is loaded the grid is displayed, but when i try to filter the weebgrid data thats were i get the error message for missing JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this code 
 `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return PartialView("Grids/_gridPremadeMeals", premadeMeals);
            else
                return View("ViewPremadeMeals", premadeMeals);` 
 
and worked. I think it was refreshing the whole page, but still cant find why..